# If $a$ is a repeating decimal, when is $c a$ a terminating decimal? $c\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

If I have a number like $a$ written in decimal expansion form, and it never ends, when will multiplying it by an integer alter this property? (I mean the result terminates at a digit.)

To be more precise,

$$a\text{ is repeating}\  \wedge\ P(c) \implies ca \text{ terminates}$$

What is $P(c)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can indeed happen, e.g. when $a = \frac17$ and $c = 7$. It will become a terminating decimal precisely when $c$ contains all factors of the denominator of $a$, except 2's and 5's.

To be more precise, if $a = \frac{x}{2^m 5^n y}$ with $x$ and $y$ relatively prime, and $y$ not divisible by 2 or 5, $c$ needs to be a multiple of $y$ in order for $ca$ to be a terminating decimal.

Comment: See the edit I made.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wrote in my answer. I hope it's clear enough; if not, please let me know.

Comment: Aha. So the second paragraph is the in fact $P(c)$. yes?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

If your original number has a *repeating* decimal representation, then multiplying it by $99\cdots99$ (with as many nines as there are digits in the repeating period) will produce a terminating decimal.

Comment: Is that the only possible way to terminate $a$?

Comment: @AHB It's not the only way, but it is _one_ way, and it is easy to find. Glorfindel's answer says how to find the other values of $c$ that will work.